# Safari media queries applied to late

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I define some media queries to better support smartphones and tablets. Now i recognized that safari make more problems then the other browsers like chrome or firefox. The biggest problem is that i define a breakpoint on a max-width of 768px but safari applied this rule on a width of 576px.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .foo { ... }
}
```

As viewport definition i use this:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
```

For testing i use the "responsive mode" in the developer options with a pixel ratio of 2 for retina displays but the problem is the same with a pixel ratio of 1.

Has someone a solution or hint for me?

Comment: Can you point to a webpage where this happens?

Comment: Extending @MrLister 's request, also please paste a snippet of your code reproducing the issue, perhaps it could be another media query that overlaps with this?